# Docker Build Succeeds Locally but Fails on GitHub Actions with Module Resolution Error

Tags: reactjs, docker, github-actions, craco, typescript-module-resolution

I am facing an issue where my Docker build succeeds locally but fails when run in a GitHub Actions workflow. The failure is specifically occurring during the build step with a module resolution error.

**Error Message:**

```
#15 [build 6/6] RUN yarn build
#15 0.372 yarn run v1.22.19
#15 0.405 $ craco build
#15 2.204 Creating an optimized production build...
#15 9.174 Failed to compile.
#15 9.174 
#15 9.175 Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@/utils/actions/api/my-axios' in '/app/src/store'
#15 9.175 
#15 9.175 
#15 9.221 error Command failed with exit code 1.
#15 9.221 info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
#15 ERROR: process "/bin/sh -c yarn build" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```

This error suggests that there's a problem with resolving the alias @ in the GitHub Actions environment, despite it working fine locally.

**craco.config.js:**

```
require("dotenv").config();
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
  webpack: {
    configure: {
      resolve: {
        fallback: {
          process: require.resolve("process/browser"),
          zlib: require.resolve("browserify-zlib"),
          stream: require.resolve("stream-browserify"),
          util: require.resolve("util"),
          buffer: require.resolve("buffer"),
          asset: require.resolve("assert"),
        },
      },
    },
    plugins: [
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        Buffer: ["buffer", "Buffer"],
        process: "process/browser",
      }),
    ],
    alias: {
      "@": path.resolve(__dirname, "src"),
    },
  },
};
```

**Dockerfile:**

```
# Use the official Node.js runtime as the base image
FROM node:19.9.0-alpine as build

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy package.json and package-lock.json (or yarn.lock, if you are using Yarn) to the container
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./

# Install project dependencies
# If you are using npm, replace with `RUN npm install`
RUN yarn install

# Copy the rest of the application code to the container
COPY . .

# Compile TypeScript to JavaScript
RUN yarn build


# Use Nginx as the production server
FROM nginx:alpine


# Copy the built React app to Nginx's web server directory
COPY nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY --from=build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
```

**package.json:**

```
    {
....
      "scripts": {
        "start": "craco start",
        "build": "craco build",
        "test": "craco test",
        "eject": "craco eject"
      },
    }
```

Comment: Is the local file system *exactly* what is available in github actions?  Can you add that information with evidence to your question?

Comment: How I can ensure that ? 
you want i provide the github action file? (yml file) ?@possum